# If x is a set of sets, there is no set containing every set that is not an element of x.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To Prove: If $x$ is a set, there is no set containing every set that is not an element of $x$.

I know that I must use the comprehension scheme and somehow reach Russel's Paradox, but I'm not sure how to set my proof up.

I am only allowed to use Empty Set Axiom, Axiom of Extensionality, Pairs, Unions, and the Comprehension Scheme.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "every set that is not an element of x", you mean that $x$ is a set of sets.

Comment: Yes! x is a set of sets.

Answer (score 0):

First we prove there is no universe:

Let $A$ be a set. Consider the set $B\triangleq\{x\in A:x\not\in x\}$. We now show $B\not\in A$.
                Suppose $B\in A$. Then either $B\in B$ or $B\not\in B$. If $B\in B$ then this implies $B\not\in B$ by
                the definition of $B$. If $B\not\in B$ we have that $B\in B$ again by the definition of $B$. Thus, we
                have $B\in B \iff B\not\in B$ which is a contradiction. Our assumption that $B\in A$ must be wrong.

Now let $x$ be a set. If there were a set $y$ which contained every set which was not in $x$, then $y\cup x$ would exist by Unions. But this set would also be the universe which does not exist. Thus such a set like $y$ cannot exist.